# Rails, storing the combination of generic and specialized attributes across types of events

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A vendor-supplied piece of software produces a text log of various messages which fail to send between various pieces of network infrastructure throughout a day. We are creating a Ruby on Rails app into which we hope to import this log, for analysis/reporting purposes.

Each log entry has a series of generic attributes, followed by a declaration of the specific type of event (specific type of message which failed to send), followed by attributes which are specific to that event type. There are approximately 20 kinds of events, each having 5-20 mostly unique attributes.

What's the best way to model this in Ruby on Rails? I have a vague impression that I'll need a model/class/table for each kind of event and its specialized attributes — but it seems like extra bulk for each of those tables to also share the generic attributes which all events share, and quite difficult to execute queries across the many tables as well.

Is there a (perhaps inheritance-based) paradigm in Rails which will allow me to store the generic attributes in a centralized table, and the specialized attributes in individual tables, while still allowing me to reference the combination of those generic and specialized attributes as an atomic "event"?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. IMO the best way with Rails is with Postgresql using the json attribute type. You could do this with one model. I would set it up like this. The model `Event`, with attributes: `kind(or type):string message:text log_attributes:json`

The `json` type is the key here, you can store an array of hashes or hashes, and when you pull it out it is just a Hash, you don't have to parse it. The same is true with storing it, you just save an array of hashes or hash. To access `event.log_attributes['SOMEKEY']`, to save `event.log_Attributes = { ruby: 'is nice', ...}`.

Here are the docs for types you can use with Postgresql and rails. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb

You need PostgreSQL 9.2 or high, which shouldn't be an issue with 10.1 coming out early this month. I have been using PostgreSQL + json + activerecord for a few years and it has made my life better.

Heads up that you can't have an attribute named attributes in rails, that is why I would name it `log_attributes`.